# Вставка данных в Ejs шаблонизатор в nodejs

Tags: node.js, javascript

Использую nodejs + express, в качестве шаблонизатора - ejs. Вопрос: могу ли я как-то из клиентского js перекинуть данные в этот шаблонизатор? То есть примерно так должно выйти: `var someVar = someData` и потом в html-файле `<%= someVar %>`.

Comment: Так ejs же без проблем работает что на сервере, что на клиенте. Не совсем понятно, какая случилась проблема.

Comment: Ну, вот, например, для того, чтобы передать данные с нода в ejs, я использую `res.render('index', {someVar: 'someVal'})`. А как мне передать переменную из клиентского js? Такое возможно?

Comment: Так и на клиенте практически так же:

    new EJS
        url: 'index.ejs'
    .render
        someVar: 'someVal'

Comment: Да, это рабочий вариант для, когда ejs подключен непосредственно к файлу. А как это сделать, когда аме это подключено через nodejs + express? Я получаю в браузере, что: Uncaught ReferenceError: EJS is not defined

Comment: Сам ejs же тоже надо подключить в браузере.

Answer (score 1):

**Jquery:**

```
$('html tag').html(someVar);
```

**js:**

```
document.body.getElementById('htmltag').innerText = somveVar;
```

Зачем усложнять